# How to JOIN two dataframes and populate a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as below,

```
DF1                                 
Name;ID;Course;SID;Subject          
Alex;A1;Under;;chemistry            
Oak;A2;Under;;chemistry             
niva;A3;grad;;physics               
mark;A4;Under;;Med

DF2
PID;ServiceId;Address;Active
A1;svc1;WI;Yes
A2;svc2;MI;Yes
A3;svc2;OH;Yes
```

I want to have a data frame with SID populated from DF2.ServiceId using ID and PID columns. The expected output as below

```
DF3                     
Name;ID;Course;SID;Subject        
Alex;A1;Under;svc1;chemistry            
Oak;A2;Under;svc2;chemistry            
niva;A3;grad;svc3;physics   
mark;A4;Under;;Med
```

I tried the below, but it showing all the columns from both the data frames.

```
DF3 = DF1.merge(DF2, how='inner', left_on="ID", right_on="PID")
```

Comment: Why are you using `left_on="SID"` if the SID column from DF1 is an entire 'null' column. If it's not the case, please provide a clear example for DF1.

Comment: I am really sorry for the typo,  using DF1.ID and DF2.PID, i have to get the corresponding ServiceId and populate it on SID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the most direct way is to reindex `df2['ServiceId']` according to `df1['ID']` vs `df2['PID']` (effectively a join), then assign the resulting values to `SID`. Although I feel like there's a cleaner way to write it.

```
df1.assign(SID=df2.set_index('PID')['ServiceId'].reindex(df1['ID']).values)
```

```
   Name  ID Course   SID    Subject
0  Alex  A1  Under  svc1  chemistry
1   Oak  A2  Under  svc2  chemistry
2  niva  A3   grad  svc3    physics
3  mark  A4  Under   NaN        Med
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a simple merge to get the answer. Try to use `how="left"` in your merge since you want to populate your first dataframe `DF1` (i.e. leaving all other values in the dataframe as the same before merge).

```
DF1.merge(DF2, left_on="ID", right_on="PID", how='left').drop('SID', axis=1).rename(columns={'ServiceId':'SID'})
```

I've done some `rename` to get the exact column names.

Outpout

```
   Name  ID Course    Subject  PID   SID Address Active
0  Alex  A1  Under  chemistry   A1  svc1      WI    Yes
1   Oak  A2  Under  chemistry   A2  svc2      MI    Yes
2  niva  A3   grad    physics   A3  svc2      OH    Yes
3  mark  A4  Under        Med  NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Good answer. And obviously other columns could simply be dropped to get exact DF3 as defined by OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandasql` and do a SQL left join instead.

```
import pandasql as pdsql

query = '''
SELECT DF1.Name, DF1.ID, DF1.Course, DF2.ServiceId as SID, DF1.Subject
FROM DF1
LEFT JOIN
     DF2
ON DF1.ID = DF2.PID
'''

DF3 = pdsql.sqldf(query)
```

```
   Name  ID Course       SID    Subject
0  Alex  A1  Under      svc1  chemistry
1   Oak  A2  Under      svc2  chemistry
2  niva  A3   grad      svc3    physics
3  mark  A4  Under      None        Med
```

If you receive an `Object Not Executable Error: Not an executable object` error when executing this query, check your `pandasql` and `sqlalchemy` versions. You may need to specifically install sqlalchemy-1.4.46 as there is currently a bug with pandasql-0.7.3 and sqlalchemy-2.0.15.